# Cordova - exporting files, where to start

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an app that generates a quick CSV of a table in JS - in browser/electron I can help users download the file by creating an href tag and doing the whole `data:` href dance. For mobile, I'm not sure where to start.

I pulled in `cordova-plugin-file` and am able to create a blob and write my file to a temporary location. I just don't know what I'm supposed to put in place to allow the user click the export button and have iOS or Android present the file for the user to do with what they please. Can anyone point me in the general direction? Maybe I'm over thinking it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the next step to get what I need to done is to use  `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` to allow users to mail the files, save to local files, etc.

Comment: For what it's worth, you're welcome to look at what we did with our project (https://github.com/adapt-it/adapt-it-mobile/blob/master/www/js/views/DocumentViews.js). We're using the socialsharing plugin, and it does seem to do the trick.